# MSHTML: CreateDocumentFromString instead of CreateDocumentFromUrl

Tags: vba, vb6, html-parsing, mshtml

I'd like to use the MSHTML library to parse some HTML that I have in a string variable.  However, I can't figure out how to do this.  I can easily parse the contents of a webpage given a known URL, but not the source HTML directly.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

```
Public Sub ParseHTML(sHTML As String)
Dim oHTML As New HTMLDocument, oDoc As HTMLDocument

    'This works:'
    Set oDoc = oHTML.createDocumentFromUrl("http://www.google.com", "")

    'I would like to do the following but no such method actually exists:'
    Set oDoc = oHTML.createDocumentFromString(sHTML)

    ....
    'Parse the HTML using the oDoc variable'
    ....
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can;

```
Dim odoc As Object

Set odoc = CreateObject("htmlfile") '// late binding

'// or:
'// Set odoc = New HTMLDocument 
'// for early binding

odoc.open
odoc.write "<p> In his house at R'lyeh, dead <b>Cthulhu</b> waits dreaming</p>"
odoc.Close
MsgBox odoc.body.outerHTML
```

Comment: Nice!  Note to others: I received a compile error in VBA when I tried to declare `odoc As HTMLDocument`: *Compile error:  Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic*.  Changing the declaration to `odoc As Object` (as this answer clearly shows) fixed the problem.

Comment: Yep, I agree, nice is the word.

Comment: @Alex: Hope you don't mind, but I edited your answer to include a way to ref the library late-bound.  It's non-obvious and took me some time to find via the web.

Comment: Early vs late binding has nothing to do with the way class is instantitated. It's the `Dim`-ensioning part that is import. `Dim ... As Object` is late binding, `Dim ... As ClassOrInterface` is early binding.

Comment: Worked, thanks!  Note that early binding caused an error for me: [Function or interface marked as restricted.](https://v5vb.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/restricted-interfaces/)

Comment: If you want to keep the early binding, you can call the restricted `Write` method using `CallByName`, like so: `CallByName odoc, "Write", vbMethod, "<p> In his house at R'lyeh, dead <b>Cthulhu</b> waits dreaming</p>"`

Answer (score 2):

For straight HTML code such as Access-Rich-Text this does it:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument

HTMLDoc.Body.innerHTML = strHTMLText
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a much better example.  You will not get a null exception, nor late binding.

(And if you use WPF, just add `System.Windows.Forms` in your reference.)

```
Dim a As Object
        a = New mshtml.HTMLDocument

        a.open()
        a.writeln(code)
        a.close()

        Do Until a.readyState = "complete"
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
        Loop


        Dim doc As mshtml.HTMLDocument = a



        Dim b As mshtml.HTMLSelectElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("Select").item("lang", 0)
```