# Can't parse phone number from a page hindered by <br> tag

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Tried to get the contact details from a page but when i run my script it only grabs the first portion of each category and ignores the rest because of some br tag, as in from contact details category it only grabs the name not the phone number or fax. Hope somebody will give me any idea how i could get that? Here is what I tried with:

```
Sub RestData()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim ele As Object, post As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set ele = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")
    For Each post In ele
        x = x + 1
        Cells(x, 1) = post.innerText
    Next post

Set html = Nothing: Set ele = Nothing: Set docs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Html element for that:

```
<p>Company Name: Vaucraft Braford Stud<br>Phone: +61 7 4942 4859<br>Fax: +61 7 4942 0618<br>Email: <a href="mailto:florfamily1@bigpond.com">florfamily1@bigpond.com</a><br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.vaucraftbrafords.com.au">http://www.vaucraftbrafords.com.au</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub RestData()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim ele As Object, post As Object
Dim TypeDetails() As String
Dim TypeDetail() As String
Dim i As Long, r As Long
With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set ele = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(2)
r = 2
TypeDetails() = Split(ele.innerText, Chr(10))

For i = 0 To UBound(TypeDetails)
    TypeDetail() = Split(TypeDetails(i), ":")
    Cells(r, 1) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(0))
    Cells(r, 2) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(1))
    r = r + 1
Next i

Set html = Nothing: Set ele = Nothing: Set docs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked. Thanks for the compliment. :)

Comment: @SMth80 Two notes: You can call `createDocumentFromUrl()` to fetch an URL directly from the `HTMLDocument` ([see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995257)) and get rid of all the MSXML2.serverXmlHttp stuff in exchange. And you can use `.querySelectorAll(".contact-details .block .dark p")` instead to streamline your DOM traversal.

Comment: Dear sir sktneer, what if I want to include Tag name p(0) and p(1) both at the same time. As this style is new to me I can't understand how to add both of them in the script. Moreover rather than making them store row wise ,I would like to store the results of each search across the column. I hope in your free time you will take a look. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Right now I am busy in a project so won't be able to look at this now. Please open a new question and post the link of your new question here. In this case other members will also be able to assist you with your new question.