# Got stuck scraping certain fields from a site

Tags: vba, split, web-scraping, responsetext

I've written a script in vba using which I can parse "Company Name", "Phone", "Fax" and "Email" from a specific site but in case of scraping "Address", "Web" and "Name" I got stuck. I've written the script using responsetext and split method in vba. Hope there is someone to show me a workaround.

Here is what i tried with:

```
str = Split(http.responseText, " class=""contact-details block dark"">")
y = UBound(str)
    For i = 1 To y
        Cells(x, 1) = Split(Split(str(i), "Company Name:")(1), "<")(0)
        Cells(x, 2) = Split(Split(str(i), "Phone:")(1), "<")(0)
        Cells(x, 3) = Split(Split(str(i), "Fax:")(1), "<")(0)
        Cells(x, 4) = Split(Split(str(i), "mailto:")(1), ">")(0)
        x = x + 1
    Next i
```

Here goes the html element stuff:

```
<div class="contact-details block dark">
                <h3>Contact Details</h3><p>Company Name: PPEHeads Australia<br>Phone: +61 2 9824 5520<br>Fax: +61 2 9824 5526<br>Web: <a target="_blank" href="http://www.ppeheads.com.au">http://www.ppeheads.com.au</a></p><h4>Address</h4><p>Unit 2 / 4 Reaghs Farm Road<br>MINTO<br>NSW<br>2566</p><h4>Contact</h4><p>Name: Alan Hadfield<br>Phone: +61 2 9824 5520<br>Fax: +61 2 9824 5526<br>Email: <a href="mailto:alan@ppeheads.com.au">alan@ppeheads.com.au</a></p>
            </div>
```

Comment: *"in case of scraping "Address", "Web" and "Name" I got stuck."* - What's your problem? Stuck where? Any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide the rest of your code next time, because the problem might not be where you think it is. Luckily I found your previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556910/cant-parse-phone-number-from-a-page-hindered-by-br-tag)

If you take a closer look there are 3 p tags within your html element:

1st one is for Contact Company Details which you can get by

```
Set ele = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(0)
```

2nd one is for Address Details which you can get by

```
Set ele2 = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(1)
```

3rd one is for Contact Person Details which you can get by

```
Set ele3 = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(2)
```

Notice (0), (1), (2) changes at the end of code which gives you the appearance order of p tag.

I amended your previous code and commented the changes so you can see the difference:

```
Sub RestData()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim ele, ele2, ele3 As Object, post As Object 'declare
Dim TypeDetails() As String
Dim TypeDetails3() As String 'declare
Dim TypeDetail() As String
Dim i As Long, r As Long
With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "http://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG0120000508&folderid=1736", False
    .send
    html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

'get all the p elements
Set ele = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(0)
Set ele2 = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(1)
Set ele3 = html.getElementsByClassName("contact-details block dark")(0).getElementsByTagName("p")(2)
r = 2

'split from line feed
TypeDetails() = Split(ele.innerText, Chr(10))
TypeDetails3() = Split(ele3.innerText, Chr(10))

'This part goes for Contact Company Details, notice the operator is ": ",not ":"
For i = 0 To UBound(TypeDetails())
    TypeDetail() = Split(TypeDetails(i), ": ")
    Cells(r, 1) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(0))
    Cells(r, 2) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(1))
    r = r + 1
Next i

'This part goes for Address Details, replaced new line with " " for it to be in the same line
Cells(r, 1) = "Address"
Cells(r, 2) = Replace(ele2.innerText, vbLf, " ")
r = r + 1

'This part goes for Contact Person Details
For i = 0 To UBound(TypeDetails3())
    TypeDetail() = Split(TypeDetails3(i), ": ")
    Cells(r, 1) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(0))
    Cells(r, 2) = VBA.Trim(TypeDetail(1))
    r = r + 1
Next i

Set html = Nothing: Set ele = Nothing: Set docs = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This definitely helps and also supersedes some method in vba in case of web parsing. Anyways, if i want those data to be displayed horizontally then there should be a slight modification in your code which is a bit hard for me to apply as i didn't work with this style before. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to switch the numbers within your Cells() function since they represent row and column respectively. They should be Cells(1,r) and Cells(2, r). You can rename r as c to represent column to avoid confusion in the future. Thank you for accepting my answer.