# Scrape a local HTML file

Tags: excel, vba, dom

I want to open a local HTML file and store it as an HTMLDocument so I can scrape it into excel. However all the available information is for html pages on the web. So for instance this code works great for www.bbc.co.uk but doesn't work for a local file:

```
Sub queryXMLlocal()
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Debug.Print Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

XMLPage.Open "GET", "<filepath>\KOND.html", False
XMLPage.send

If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then
MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLPage.Status & " - " & XMLPage.statusText
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Alternatively using

```
Sub GetHTMLDocument()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.internetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument


IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.bbc.co.uk/"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

    ' Wait while IE loading...

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
end sub
```

works but when I use a local file I get the error:

> "object invoked has disconnected from its client"

Can I just use `HTMLdocument.open`? Although I cannot get this to work either.

Comment: If it's not being served by an web server, what's going to respond to an HTTP request? Along those same lines, why would you need to "scrape" it? Are you storing data as HTML?

Comment: You will need to load the local file into a string then you can write that into a new `HTMLDocument`. See [MSHTML: CreateDocumentFromString instead of CreateDocumentFromUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995257/mshtml-createdocumentfromstring-instead-of-createdocumentfromurl)

Comment: Alex K. Thanks so much. This is my final code and it seems to work:
Sub loadLocalfileAsString()
Dim myFile As String
Dim text As String
Dim textline As String
Dim odoc As Object

myFile = "filepath\KOND.html"

Open myFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

Set odoc = New HTMLDocument
odoc.Open
odoc.Write text
odoc.Close

End Sub

Comment: Comintern, Yes bizarrely I am getting an HTML file in from some ftp process and I need to  get data out of if and put into excel.

Answer (score 3):

This is the function I usually use:

```
Public Function GetHTMLFileContent(ByVal filePath As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim fso As Object, hFile As Object, hString As String, html As New HTMLDocument
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set hFile = fso.OpenTextFile(filePath)

    Do Until hFile.AtEndOfStream
        hString = hFile.ReadAll()
    Loop

    html.body.innerHTML = hString
    Set GetHTMLFileContent = html
End Function
```

Comment: tkx QHarr nice solution

Comment: No worries. :-)

Comment: The last line of your solution is giving me Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method